# Select one column using Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Does anyone have any idea how to get a single column using Spring Data JPA? I created a repository like below in my Spring Boot project, but always get the `{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}` error when accessing the Restful URL.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UsersRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT u.userName  FROM Users u")
    public List<String> getUserName();
}
```

Then if I access the Restful URL like `../users/search/getUserName`, I get the error:
`{"cause":null,"message":"PersistentEntity must not be null!"}`

Comment: This works for me with JpaRepository.

Answer (score 12):

Create a Projection interface

```
public interface UserNameOnly {
    String getUserName();
}
```

Then in your repository interface return that type instead of the user type

```
public interface UserRepository<User> extends JpaRepository<User,String> {
    List<UsernameOnly> findNamesByUserNameNotNull();
}
```

The get method in the projection interface must match a get method of the defined type on the JPA repository, in this case User.
The "findBySomePropertyOnTheObjectThatIsNotNull" allows you to get a List of the entities (as opposed to an Iterable) based on some criteria, which for a findAll can simply be if the unique identifier (or any other NonNull field) is not null.

Comment: @Alax would you consider possibly accepting my answer?

Comment: It's not the solution tbh, projection selects all the fields anyways.

Comment: I think James forgot to add `@Query` in the `UserRepository` interface. I have edited the @James code. Hope this will return only UserName.

Comment: No I didnt. The Query annontation is not necessary as Spring Data JPA can parse the method name to determine what query to run.

Comment: @Boldbayar, your statement is not correct. For closed projections, where the method names on the interface match getters on the entity ... the Hibernate sql logs confirm that only the fields present in the interface are queried for. Open projections, where SPEL expressions are used to calculate field values, cannot be optimized, and in that case you would be correct.

Answer (score 5):

Concept is : In your entity class create a constructor with only required instant variables. And use that constructor in the repository method shown below.

Lets say you have a interface Repository like below

1. Repository implementation:

   ```
   public interface UserRepository<User> extends JpaRepository<User,String>
   {
       @Query(value = "select new com.org.User(usr.userId) from User usr where usr.name(:name)")
       List<User> findUserIdAlone(@Param("name") String user);
   }
   ```
2. In Controller

   ```
   @RestController
   public class UserController 
   {
       @Autowired
       private UserRepository<User> userRepository; 

       @Res
       public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable("usrname") String userName)
       {
           User resultUser = usrRepository.findUserIdAlone(userName);
           return ResponseEntity.ok(resultUser);
       }
   }

   public class User 
   {

       private String userId,userName;

       public User(String userId) 
       {
           this.userId=userId;
       }
       // setter and getters goes here
   }
   ```

Comment: Is that an extra bracket on the @Query(value = "select new com.org.User(usr.userId) from User usr where usr.name(:name))") section?

Comment: @AzySır removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This Works for me.

```
public interface UserDataRepository extends JpaRepository<UserData, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT emp_name FROM user_data", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> findEmp_name();
}


System.out.println("data"+  userDataRepository.findEmp_name());
```

The above line gave me this result :

data[abhijeet, abhijeet1, abhijeet2, abhijeet3, abhijeet4, abhijeet5]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with a Custom Object.

If you see where you have Object[] I have a custom object and it has not worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only return a single column you should look at [Projections and Excerpts](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) which will allow you to filter specific columns and other things that are usefule.

Answer (score 0):

If you need list all of the users, try `select userName from Users`, if you need one user use `"where"` look at spring data JPA  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/ , try change CrudRepository to JpaRepository

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Actually, it still does not work. I got the same error. If to list all columns, it works, but not if just part of them.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to provide custom implementations of methods in a Spring Data JPA repository, which enables complete control on queries and return types. The approach is as follows:

- Define an interface with the desired method signatures.
- Implement the interface to achieve the desired behavior.
- Have the Repository extend both `JpaRepository` and the custom interface.

Here is a working example that uses `JpaRepository`, assuming a `user_table` with two columns, `user_id` and `user_name`.

UserEntity class in model package:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_table")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    protected UserEntity() {}

    public UserEntity(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Define interface for the custom repository in the repository package:

```
public interface UserCustomRepository {
    List<String> findUserNames();
}
```

Provide implementation class for the custom interface in the repository package:

```
public class UserCustomRepositoryImpl implements UserCustomRepository {


    // Spring auto configures a DataSource and JdbcTemplate
    // based on the application.properties file. We can use
    // autowiring to get a reference to it.
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    // Now our custom implementation can use the JdbcTemplate
    // to perform JPQL queries and return basic datatypes.
    @Override
    public List<String> findUserNames() throws DataAccessException {
        String sql = "SELECT user_name FROM user_table";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, String.class);
    }
}
```

Finally, we just need to have the `UserRepository` extend both `JpaRepository` and the custom interface we just implemented.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserEntity, Long>, UserCustomRepository {}
```

Simple test class with junit 5 (assuming the database is initially empty):

```
@SpringBootTest
class UserRepositoryTest {

    private static final String JANE = "Jane";
    private static final String JOE = "Joe";

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repo;

    @Test
    void shouldFindUserNames() {
        UserEntity jane = new UserEntity(JANE);
        UserEntity joe = new UserEntity(JOE);

        repo.saveAndFlush(jane);
        repo.saveAndFlush(joe);

        List<UserEntity> users = repo.findAll();
        assertEquals(2, users.size());

        List<String> names = repo.findUserNames();
        assertEquals(2, names.size());
        assertTrue(names.contains(JANE));
        assertTrue(names.contains(JOE));
    }

}
```